# Loading Sampler Instrument Failing In El Capitan

Tags: objective-c, xcode, macos, avfoundation

I've written a Mac app using SpriteKit. My sampler instrument, which is an `AVAudioUnitSampler`, is no longer loading for some reason. This problem only came about since I've updated my system to El Capitan from Yosemite. I haven't touched the code since I was running Yosemite. My deployment target is still Yosemite, although I changed it to El Cap and it crashes. Any ideas?

Here's the stack trace:

```
2016-09-12 10:59:01.134 Playground[66431:1254259] removed
2016-09-12 10:59:03.747 Playground[66431:1254301] sampler loaded
2016-09-12 10:59:03.848 Playground[66431:1254285] 10:59:03.848 ERROR:    93: BankEntry::LoadInstrument: Unable to find patch 0 bank 0x78/0
2016-09-12 10:59:03.848 Playground[66431:1254285] 10:59:03.848 ERROR:    486: DLS/SF2 bank load failed
2016-09-12 10:59:03.859 Playground[66431:1254285] 10:59:03.859 ERROR:    AVAudioUnitSampler.mm:163: -[AVAudioUnitSampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:program:bankMSB:bankLSB:error:]: error -10851
2016-09-12 10:59:03.861 Playground[66431:1254285] An uncaught exception was raised
2016-09-12 10:59:03.861 Playground[66431:1254285] error -10851
2016-09-12 10:59:03.861 Playground[66431:1254285] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff946594f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9c4da73c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9465e1ca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff9b29ce13 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176
    4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff9b2d5dae -[AVAudioUnitSampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:program:bankMSB:bankLSB:error:] + 317
    5   Playground                          0x0000000100017800 __41-[MIDIController loadSoundFontInstrument]_block_invoke + 96
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003a1070 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100393cc5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100398457 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2934
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003978a5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003f6336 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003f3f91 start_wqthread + 13
)

2016-09-12 10:59:03.861 Playground[66431:1254285] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'com.apple.coreaudio.avfaudio', reason: 'error -10851'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff946594f2 __exceptionPreprocess + 178
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff9c4da73c objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9465e1ca +[NSException raise:format:arguments:] + 106
    3   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff9b29ce13 _Z19AVAE_RaiseExceptionP8NSStringz + 176
    4   libAVFAudio.dylib                   0x00007fff9b2d5dae -[AVAudioUnitSampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:program:bankMSB:bankLSB:error:] + 317
    5   Playground                          0x0000000100017800 __41-[MIDIController loadSoundFontInstrument]_block_invoke + 96
    6   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003a1070 _dispatch_call_block_and_release + 12
    7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100393cc5 _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000100398457 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 2934
    9   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001003978a5 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 106
    10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003f6336 _pthread_wqthread + 1129
    11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001003f3f91 start_wqthread + 13
)

libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Here's the code where I load the sampler:

**MIDIController.h**

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface MIDIController : NSObject

@property NSMutableArray *notes;
@property NSMutableArray *keyboard;
@property CFStringRef endpointName;

@property AVAudioUnitSampler *sampler;

-(int)uniqueNotesPlayed;
-(void) loadSampler;
-(void) unloadSampler;
@end
```

**MIDIController.m**

```
...

-(void) loadSampler {
    // Instatiate audio engine
    _engine = [[AVAudioEngine alloc] init];
    _mixer = [_engine mainMixerNode];
    _sampler = [[AVAudioUnitSampler alloc] init];

    [self loadSoundFontInstrument];

    [self makeEngineConnections];
    [self startEngine];
}

-(void) loadSoundFontInstrument {
    if (_sampler != nil) {
        NSString *instrument = [[GameData sharedGameData].settings valueForKey:@"instrument"];
        NSURL *piano = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:instrument ofType:@"sf2"]];

        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0), ^{
            [_sampler loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL:piano program:0 bankMSB:0x79 bankLSB:0 error:nil];
        });
    }
    else
        NSLog(@"ERROR: Sampler has not been initialized");
}
...
```

Comment: `loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL` is reporting `kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue` because "Unable to find patch 0 bank 0x78/0". Maybe the piano sound font file isn't considered valid on elcap? Out of interest, can you try loading it on the main dispatch queue? Or without `dispatch_async`?

Comment: Hmm...isn't sound font a fairly old standard? I have to say, you are a genius though. I took the creation of the `_sampler` out of the `dispatch_async` and it worked!!! Any ideas why that is? Race condition of some sort?

Comment: Yeah, working no matter where you're called from isn't a simple requirement.

Comment: Hmm...I don't know how it worked for so long. Perhaps there were changes in the AV APIs that caused things to go crazy. Thanks again!

Comment: If you want to post your solution to this, I'll happily select it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*answer migrated from comments*

`loadSoundBankInstrumentAtURL` is reporting `kAudioUnitErr_InvalidPropertyValue` because "Unable to find patch 0 bank 0x78/0". Maybe the piano sound font file isn't considered valid on elcap?

Out of interest, can you try loading it on the main dispatch queue? Or without the `dispatch_async`?

Being callable from multiple threads is a difficult requirement (and did anybody actually claim that `AVAudioUnitSampler` was threadsafe?), so it wouldn't surprise me if that was the cause of your woes.